# how to 2 observable collection in xaml for windows phone application?

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, data-binding, itemtemplate, panorama-control

i have 2 observable collection in mainviewmodel, now i need to bind this two collection into the xaml file.

```
<!--Panorama control-->
<controls:Panorama x:Name="AppPano" ItemsSource="{Binding SlidesCollections}" SelectionChanged="AppPano_SelectionChanged" >
    <controls:Panorama.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="PanoramaBackground.png"/>
    </controls:Panorama.Background>

    <controls:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,-100,0,0">
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="250" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="200" Width="Auto"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <ListBox x:Name="ItemsList" ItemsSource="{Binding SlideItemList}" Margin="0,250,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="ItemsList_SelectionChanged" Height="430">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel x:Name="ImgStack" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="430" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="370" Margin="50,0,0,0">
                                <Image Height="350" Width="360" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
</controls:Panorama>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
   public KidsAppMainViewModel()
    {
        this.SlidesCollections = new ObservableCollection<AppItemsListViewModel>();

        this.SlideItemList = new ObservableCollection<AppItemViewModel>();

    }

  public ObservableCollection<AppItemsListViewModel> SlidesCollections {get; set;}

  public ObservableCollection<AppItemViewModel> SlideItemList {get; set;}
```

MainXaml.cs

```
  DataContext = App.ViewModel
```

App.xaml.cs

```
  public static MainViewModel viewModel = new MainViewModel();
  public MainViewModel ViewModel
  { get { return viewModel;}}
```

Problem:

When i run the application the panorama item template binding works fine, but the list item template doesn't work for me. i have tried by other way using collectionview source, its works for me but it was too slow for binding items.

Pls suggest me how to bind this collection directly..

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your xaml markup, You need to have `SlideItemList` inside `AppItemsListViewModel`.

Comment: actually i have done by your way.. it repeatedly display the images.. so i don't want continue with that.. Is there any other way to bind it..

Comment: what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: I have panorama with 3 or 4 pages. every page i need to display images and etc in the list box for the particular panorama item.

Comment: If you want SlideItemList to be displayed in every AppItemsListViewModel item then what I said is correct. If you meant something else then describe it clearly.